# Drive Animation with ValueNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have `ValueNotifier<double>` that I need to pass to `FadeTransition`'s opacity. Issue is that this opacity parameter is of type `Animation<double>`.

What would be minimal way of converting `ValueNotifier<double>` to `Animation<double>`. Is there any Animation type that allows manually setting the current value?

I know there is `AnimationController`, but it needs too much boilerplate. It requires a `TickerProvider` that in this case isn't useful at all.

I'm looking for lightweight `Animation<>` implementation that is similar to `ValueNotifier<>`.

Comment: are you sure that your `ValueNotifier<double>` changes its `value` over the time? if so, post the code where it is done, also cannot you just use `AnimatedOpacity`?

Comment: ViewModel listens to ScrollController and based on scroll offset calculates current opacity value that is then stored inside a ValueNotifier<double>. I guess alternative would be to create Animation<double> from ScrollController, but I'm not sure which animation class is appropriate to do the transformation of offset to opacity. Opacity is animated just for a specific range of the scroll offset.

Comment: so use `ValuelistenableBuilder`, pass your `ValueNotifier` and return `Opacity` from the `builder:`

Comment: alternatively you could create a class similar to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animations.dart#L166) and override `value` property

Comment: That's what the old code is doing. However, I'm trying to optimize performance of this specific screen and docs for Opacity class recommend using  AnimatedOpacity or a FadeTransition instead, if opacity is being animated.

Comment: so, as I said create a custom `Animation` class, similar to `ProxyAnimation`

Comment: I just created an animation class that wraps `ValueNotifier`. It works, but I'm not sure if I need to implement dispose method. I'll post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I created this simple ValueNotifier wrapper. It works, <s>but I'm not sure, if it also needs dispose method.</s>

EDIT: Dispose is not needed since it only passes listeners to an outside ValueNotifier object.

```
class ValueNotifierWrapperAnimation<T> extends Animation<T>
    with AnimationLocalStatusListenersMixin {
  ValueNotifierWrapperAnimation(this.valueNotifier);

  final ValueNotifier<T> valueNotifier;

  @override
  AnimationStatus get status => AnimationStatus.forward;

  @override
  T get value => valueNotifier.value;

  @override
  void addListener(VoidCallback listener) =>
      valueNotifier.addListener(listener);

  @override
  void removeListener(VoidCallback listener) =>
      valueNotifier.removeListener(listener);

  @override
  void didRegisterListener() {}

  @override
  void didUnregisterListener() {}
}
```

---

EDIT 2: Instead of wrapper, a class that holds it's own value and acts both as ValueNotifier and Animation. Compared to the previous implementation, this removes a requirement to also have a ValueNotifier field somewhere.

```
class ValueNotifierAnimation<T> extends Animation<T>
    with AnimationLocalListenersMixin, AnimationLocalStatusListenersMixin {

  ValueNotifierAnimation(this._value);

  T _value;

  @override
  T get value => _value;

  set value(T newValue) {
    if (_value == newValue)
      return;
    _value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  AnimationStatus get status => AnimationStatus.forward;

  @override
  void didRegisterListener() {}

  @override
  void didUnregisterListener() {}

  @override
  String toString() => '${describeIdentity(this)}($value)';
}
```

Comment: you dont need that extra `ValueNotifier` - check [ValueNotifierAnimation](https://gist.github.com/pskink/4839ad3ecdcc6f15e7f7653829c8fce6#file-value_notifier_animation-dart-L86) - sample usage in the commented `ValueNotifierAnimationTest` widget above

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed simpler to use. I've updated the answer.